# using __del__ with property methods in place

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Property wrapper methods is a nice feature to have in python, this question is not the subject of such question, I need to know if it is possible to use it with python destructor `__del__`, a practical example could be a database connection, for simplification purposes let's say we have the following class:

```
class Point(object):
"""docstring for Point"""

def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y

@property
def x(self):
    print('x getter got called')
    return self._x

@x.setter
def x(self, x):
    print('x setter got called')
    self._x = x

def __str__(self):
    return '[%s:%s]' % (self.x, self.y)

def __del__(self):
    print('destructor got called')
    del self.x
    del self.y
```

as a test case let's say we have:

```
a = Point(4, 5)
del a
```

The output is:

```
Exception AttributeError: "can't delete attribute" in <bound method Point.__del__ of <__main__.Point object at 0x7f8bcc7e5e10>> ignored
```

if we deleted the property part, everything goes smooth.
can someone show where's the problem?

Comment: you want `del self._x`

Comment: This works perfectly fine, do you have any idea what's better to handle object deconstruction using the @x.deleter or handle all the deconstruction for all the object properties inside the __del__ method, with the second option we are writing less code.

Comment: @ponach generally, you should avoid using `__del__` for this, you can easily cause memory leaks. Rather, use a context manager.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga can you elaborate further on how to use context manager for this specific case, freeing up resources any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @ponach check [this](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2016/03/07/python-with-context-managers/) out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a deleter to your property `x` that does the clean up. By default, if no `fdel` is defined for the property, [the `AttributeError` you see](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/descrobject.c#L1419) is raised:

```
@x.deleter
def x(self):
    print("x deleter got called")
    del self._x
```

Comment: This works perfectly fine, do you have any idea what's better to handle object deconstruction using the @x.deleter or handle all the deconstruction for all the object properties inside the __del__ method, with the second option we are writing less code.

Comment: @ponach Though I personally can't think of a downside of using `del self._x` in `__del__` (someone might know one and I hope they chime in) it is definetily semantically superior to let the property be responsible for the deletion of an attribute it manages.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't use `@x.deleter` to define the delete behavior (like you did with `@x.setter`) then it's impossible to delete the property.